# Local Apache Tomcat cannot access Internet due to company proxy

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, proxy

I am a Java developer for Magnolia CMS. On my company's Windows PC I am running IntelliJ Ultimate 2020 and Tomcat 9.0.33. I deploy Magnolia jar via Maven.
My problem is:
The Tomcat cannot access any web resources. However, there are quite a few situations where the CMS (and not the client browser) need to access resources on the internet. Simply doesn't work.

I am very sure that this is because of my company's internet proxy. All other developers on the project are not behind this proxy and have no problems with the exact same code base / tomcat / intellij settings.

However, for the life of me I cannot get the connection to work. I read and tried many different ways of adding proxy settings to Tomcat but nothing seems to work.

Info: I tried both the company proxy and the additional CNTLM proxy that I use e.g. for Maven

1. Proxy is set in IntelliJ options. IntelliJ can successfully download packages etc.
2. I tried setting JVM options in IntelliJ -> doesn't help

[image]

3. I tried setting proxy in catalina.bat and/or startup.bat -> shows up in logs of server startup, doesn't help

```
rem Setup UI Proxy
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -DproxySet=true"
```

Any hints and help are very much appreciated!

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, if your company requires a proxy, 127.0.0.1 is rarely the correct one

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is CNTLM proxy, I tried every option with company proxy and the CNTLM proxy. As I said, Maven works great with CNTLM.

Comment: And I added the image so it is relatable as to where I made those settings in IntelliJ. It’s not about the code but about the place where the code is set.